# Why is object.function.this is undefined when using function.call?

Tags: javascript, object, call

I'm trying to use call to link a `setInterval` function (intervalFunc) and `move()` a function contained in a object. Whenever I use it I got the following

```
error:"shooter2.js:46 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"
```

`this.id` is apparently undefined but I can't figure out why.

```
 //SPACESHIP
 var spaceShip=
{
  width:20,
  height:35,
  x:700,
  y:665
}

// Set SpaceShip start position
document.getElementById("dv_spaceShip").style.left=spaceShip.x+"px";
document.getElementById("dv_spaceShip").style.top=spaceShip.y+"px";




// SHOTS
var shotsArray = [];
var shotCount=-1;
function shotConstruct(id)
{
  this.id=id,
  this.interval;
 this.createHtml=function(){

// Creating a new div and attaching it to the dv_global
var setDiv=document.createElement("div");
var setId=setDiv.setAttribute("id",this.id);
document.getElementById("dv_global").appendChild(setDiv);

var shotId= document.getElementById(this.id);
console.log("shotId="+shotId);
// Creating physical elements
shotId.style.width=this.width+"px";
shotId.style.height=this.height+"px";
shotId.style.backgroundColor=this.BGcolor;
shotId.style.position="absolute";
shotId.style.left=spaceShip.x+3.5+"px";
shotId.style.top=this.y+"px";
   }

  //Moving the shot
  this.move=function(){
  console.log("this.id"+this.id);
  document.getElementById(this.id).style.top=50+"px";
    }

    }

// Properties and methods shared by all shots
shotConstruct.prototype.width=10;
shotConstruct.prototype.height=10;
shotConstruct.prototype.speed=10;
shotConstruct.prototype.BGcolor="#000099";
shotConstruct.prototype.y=655;



    function intervalFunc(){
    setInterval(this.move,2000);
    }


  function shoot()
  { 
  // Clears the array containing all shots, may be optionnal
  shotsArray=[];
  shotCount+=1;
  shotsArray.push("Shot"+shotCount);
  //console.log(shotsArray[0]);
  shotsArray[0]=new shotConstruct(shotsArray[0]);
   //console.log(shotsArray[0]);
   console.log(shotsArray[0]);
  // Create html elements for each shot.
   shotsArray[0].createHtml();
  //shotsArray[0].move();
  shotsArray[0].interval=intervalFunc.call(shotsArray[0]);
 }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: `.call()` doesn't link anything. It just calls the function and sets the first argument you get as the `this` value of the function. Your `intervalFunc` doesn't return anything, so you're just setting `shotsArray[0].interval` to `undefined`. And you're passing `this.move` as the `setInterval()` callback, which detaches `move` from `this`, so `move` will not have the expected `this` value.

Comment: What shall I do then?

Answer (score 0):

`call()` first parameter is the `this` for the executed function:

```
intervalFunc.call(this, shotsArray[0]);
```

When using setInterval you are loosing `this` again so change to:

```
setInterval(this.move.bind(this), 2000);
```